# Is there a way not to generate directory for services in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli and starting from version 1.4 they decided to create directory not only for components(that is fine by my) but also for services with only 2 files in it: service and test.

```
✗ ng g s users
  create src/app/users/users.service.spec.ts
  create src/app/users/users.service.ts
```

Is there a way not to generate this useless directory?

Comment: You can see the options for commands in the wiki. In this case, looks like you want `--flat`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-service

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why everyone is downvoting this question, it is a perfectly reasonable question to ask...

I'm on 1.4.4 and if I run:

```
ng g s users
```

It doesn't make the directory for me, only the file itself. Make sure you are running cmd in the app folder.